# tar extracted archive removes version

Tags: bash, gzip, tar, php-ziparchive

I have a zipped archive version 0.0.1: `myarch_0.0.1.tar.gz`

When I extract it with tar, everything is unzipped and extracted in a `myarch` folder, stripping the version number.

```
ls
myarch_0.0.1.tar.gz

tar -zxvf myarch_0.0.1.tar.gz

ls
myarch/ myarch_0.0.1.tar.gz*
```

I want the extracted folder to be named: `myarch_0.0.1/`
How do I keep my version number stuck to the extracted folder name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of an archive file, and the name of the files inside, have nothing to do with each other in general. If you want extracted directories to have a certain name, with a version number, then you have to create the archive with so named directories.

In this example, the extracted content is a directory named `myarch`, instead of your desired `myarch_0.0.1`. You can rename the directory and recreate the archive:

```
mv myarch myarch_0.0.1
tar zcf myarch_0.0.1.tar.gz myarch_0.0.1
```

That's it. When you untar this new archive, you will get a directory named `myarch_0.0.1`, simply because that's what you put inside. Even if you rename this file to `mickeymouse.tar.gz`, when you untar it, you will still get a directory named `myarch_0.0.1`, simply because that's what's inside the archive. Nothing to do with the filename of the archive.